# Unable to loop through all elements in an array of objects; ngFor or iteration in the component only gives me the first element

Tags: arrays, angular, object

This may sound strange, at least I find it strange or something very basic is escaping me:
After mapping the API response, I manage to store an array of 10 objects into a variable. the data looks like this:[image]

This is the method that gets the data. The log shown comes from `this.finalPhraseResults`:

```
receivedPhrase(value){
    this.guardian.searchByPhrase(value)
    .subscribe(result=>{
      this.phraseResults=Array.of(result).map(x=>x['response'])
      this.finalPhraseResults = this.phraseResults.map(x=>x['results']);
     console.log(this.finalPhraseResults)
    })
  }
```

And the HTML

```
<ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let p of finalPhraseResults">
      <li class="list-group-item">
        {{p.type}}
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        {{p.sectionId}}
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        {{p.sectionName}}
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        {{p.webPublicationDate}}
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="goToPhraseExternal(p.id)">Go to article</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

The result is a blank page. But if I write something like this:

```
this.finalPhraseResults = this.phraseResults.map(x=>x['results'][0]);
```

I get data rendered but only from the first object, obviously. So I'm kind of lost here. Can someone explain to me what is happening?

EDIT
The Original response @Michael D
[image]

Comment: If could provide the original response `result`, we could come up with a way to initialize the `this.finalPhraseResults` without the array of array issue.

Comment: Are you sure the screenshot is of the `result` and not the `this.phraseResults`? You seem to mapping to a property called `response` from the result, but it isn't to be found in the posted screenshot.

Comment: I'm mapping from a property called response which is an object that I turn into an array. Then I create the second array only with the results property

Comment: In that case you continue using the same procedure and access the item directly with `[0]` or use another enclosed `*ngFor`. Or if you're sure the first array will contain only one element, you could say `this.phraseResults=Array.of(result).map(x=>x['response'])['results']` and ignore the `[0]` in the template.

Comment: ok, that will work as well, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is an array of an array. The quick fix would be

Controller

```js
this.finalPhraseResults = this.phraseResults.map(x=>x['results']);
```

Template

```html
<ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let p of finalPhraseResults[0]">
  ...
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, both of you. Now it seems all very clear. I marked correct the second answer because it worked instantly. The other needed more fixes, thanks anyway!

Comment: it also works like this: `      this.phraseResults=Array.of(result).map(x=>x['response']).map(x=>x['results'])`

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have an array of array. try this:

```js
this.phraseResults=Array.of(result).map(x=>x['response'])
this.finalPhraseResults = this.phraseResults[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new variable to store final Phrase Results and ngFor* with that array.  New class should be defined with all the properties.

```
public class FinalPhraseResult{
public string id;
public string type;
public string sectionId;
}
```

now in your ts file you can declare a variable  public finalPhraseResult:FinalPhraseResult[] = [];

In your subscribe you can assign value to this new array this.finalPhraseResult = this.phraseResults.map(x=>x['results'])[0];

This is the important part, as the result return is also an array,you have to select the from index 0.

In the html template you can now use

```
<ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let p of finalPhraseResult">
  ...
</ul>
```